# Stored Procedures in SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-express

I am well aware of SQL statements such as select, insert, update and delete. However I am new to stored procedures.

I am using SQL Management Studio Express.

Any code example? For example, Registration, a stored procedure that saves the customer data in the database.

Comment: Is  there a question in there somewhere?  Hint - if you don't have any question marks `?` in your "question" it may be unclear what you are asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing about using stored procedures in preference to embedded SQL is that, done properly, they present a versionable interface to the database that is independent of the client code. It gets the SQL out of the client codebase, which means that so long as the external interface doesn't change: parameters, results sets, etc., the DBAs are free to tune queries or even completely remodel the database schema without requiring changes to the client software.

It also hugely simplifies security. Clients don't require permission grants to the underlying tables themselves. All they need is `grant execute` on the stored procedures.

If all you do is write a stored procedures that wrap simple insert/update/delete statements, you're not really accomplishing much. The stored procedures should represent more logical operations.

Remember, any real database will long outlive the software used to access it. Data is forever; software is transient.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid SQL injection - stored procedures are not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Nice article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) explaining how to avoid SQL Injection attacks. Read the Addition Considerations.

The simpliest way to put it is to paramaterise all your queries like below

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
  SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter( 
             "LoginStoredProcedure", connection);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@au_id"].Value = SSN.Text;

  myCommand.Fill(userDataset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example as you requested:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTeste(@MyParam INT)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CodTable = @MyParam;
END;
```

To call it from another location passing 5 as parameter, do:

```
EXEC MyTeste 5;
```